# wget for windows error: tlsv1 alert protocol version Unable to establish SSL connection

Tags: ssl, windows-10, wget

I am trying to use the wget binary for windows, in order to download an entire website onto a USB drive. I tried to run the following wget command, but it just failed. I don't know why. I don't know how to read the following error message.

with http:

```
E:\gardening> wget --mirror --convert-links --html-extension --no-timestamping --no-clobber -erobots=off --page-requisites --user-agent=Mozilla http://www.eattheweeds.com/
--2022-07-12 17:48:33--  http://www.eattheweeds.com/
Resolving www.eattheweeds.com... 45.60.22.231
Connecting to www.eattheweeds.com|45.60.22.231|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.eattheweeds.com/ [following]
--2022-07-12 17:48:33--  https://www.eattheweeds.com/
Connecting to www.eattheweeds.com|45.60.22.231|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

with https:

```
E:\gardening> wget --mirror --convert-links --html-extension --no-timestamping --no-clobber -erobots=off --page-requisites --user-agent=Mozilla https://www.eattheweeds.com/
--2022-07-12 17:45:38--  https://www.eattheweeds.com/
Resolving www.eattheweeds.com... 45.60.22.231
Connecting to www.eattheweeds.com|45.60.22.231|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I got my wget from this website.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/wget/1.11.4-1/wget-1.11.4-1-setup.exe/download?use_mirror=cfhcable

Could my version of wget have something to do with this?

```
GNU Wget 1.11.4

Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc
```

---

Edit:

I downloaded wget version `GNU Wget 1.21.3 built on mingw32` and it worked!

https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/

https://builtvisible.com/download-your-website-with-wget/

Comment: A much more pertinent question than what version of wget you built is which SSL library you built it against. Note that SSLv2 and SSLv3 are ancient and considered insecure, and TLSv1 is frowned on in some places too -- more cautious servers these days only allow TLSv1.3.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy And how do I find that? I didn't built wget from source. I just downloaded the windows installer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Are there some command arguments that you can provide to wget to make it use SSLv2, SSLv3, TLSv1, or TLSv1.3? And which one should I use?

Comment: Depends on how it's linked (if it's dynamically linked, any `objdump` or `ldd`-style tool can tell you which library it's linked to), but if you aren't compiling it yourself it's off-topic here. We're only for questions about developing software.

Comment: That said -- there are plenty of online tools that can test a website and tell you which SSL or TLS versions it's compatible with; then you can check your client software and see what _it's_ compatible with, and determine whether it's the client or the server side that's trying to use an unreasonably old protocol.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ok, what would you suggest me to do? Try to compile wget from source code on windows? I am used to compiling software from the source code on linux, but I don't know how to do that on windows, as I've always used installers.

Comment: Personally, the thing I would try next is to uninstall the binary you currently have, and then install wget with cygwin -- the cygwin version should be considerably more up-to-date than what you have now.

Comment: (also, cygwin's installer will tell you which openssl version they're using, reducing need for guesswork)

Comment: (the edit specifying a wget version from 2008 does imply it's probably a client-side problem; if the openssl version is from 2008 as well, it _definitely_ won't support modern protocol variants).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, it was an old version of wget. I got a newer version and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your version of `wget` do not support new versions of TLS. And the web site need TLS v1.1 or 1.2. As you found you need new version of `wget`

As you use Windows next time maybe will be wise to use Power Shell which have incorporated version of `wget`

Comment: I have Linux too, but I wanted to download the file onto my Windows PC.

Comment: @Galaxy, rigth, use PowerShell on Windows and command `wget` (w/o `.exe`) :)